# Change of entropy of surroundings in reversible and irreversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am currently in high school and trying to gain some conceptual clarity on entropy and the second law of thermodynamics which led me to read various answers on this forum and i have referred some other texts as my textbook does not explain much about the differences in irreversible and reversible process. I have written my understanding so far and would appreciate if anyone could help point out any mistakes and clarify some doubts.

I have learnt that change entropy in a reversible process is a state function and therefore $\Delta$ S over a cyclic process should be zero and entropy change of a system in an irreversible process can be calculated by imagining a suitable reversible process that takes you between the initial and final states of the system. Further in a reversible process  $\Delta$ $S_{sys}$ + $\Delta$ $S_{surr}$ = 0.
In an irreversible process this does not hold true due to $S_{gen}$ created due to internal irreversible changes.

I have read that due to the clausius inequality $\Delta$ $S$ = $\int \frac{dQ}{T}$ + $S_{gen}$ but here i am confused about whether the dq they are talking about is due to an irreversible path or a reversible one and if the change in entropy is of the system or surroundings. I thought it would be of the surroundings but i am confused as my textbook just says $\Delta$ $S_{surr}$ =  $\int \frac{dQ_{irrev}}{T}$.

Also since entropy change of the system is a state function regardless of whether the path is reversible or not is it correct to say that $\Delta$ $S_{surr}$ in an irreversible process is a path function as $\Delta$ $S_{uni}$ >0 in a cyclic process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that due to the clausius inequality $\Delta$ $S$ = $\int
>  \frac{dQ}{T}$ + $S_{gen}$ but here i am confused about whether the dq
> they are talking about is due to an irreversible path or a reversible
> one

The $dQ$ is for any path. The temperature $T$ in the equation is the temperature at the boundary between the system and the surroundings, which is in this case a thermal reservoir. It is helpful to write it as $T_{B}$ to account for the possibility that the system temperature $T$ may not be the same as the temperature at the boundary $T_B$.

$dQ$ is reversible if the system is in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir, that is, when $T_{B}=T$ where $T$ is the equilibrium temperature of the system. In that case no entropy is generated and $S_{gen}=0$. If $T \ne T_{B}$ then the heat is irreversible and $S_{gen}\gt 0$.

> Also since entropy change of the system is a state function regardless
> of whether the path is reversible or not is it correct to say that
> $\Delta$ $S_{surr}$ in an irreversible process is a path function as
> $\Delta$ $S_{uni}$ >0 in a cyclic process

Entropy is a state function for both the system and the surroundings. (One could just as well reverse the definitions of the system and surroundings).

For an irreversible ***system cycle,*** $\Delta S_{surr}\gt0$ is due to the fact that the surroundings has not completed a cycle as it has acquired the entropy that was generated in the system in order for the system to complete its cycle so that $\Delta S_{sys}=0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh ok this helps, i was under the misconception that system and surrounding cycles would be the same. So is it possible to have $\Delta$ $S_{surr}$ = 0 assuming an irreversible process but here the system would not have a net zero change?

Comment: @JeffJefferson "Assuming an irreversible process" where?

Comment: the answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: @BobD It was an assumption on my part, i apologize if it wasnt framed well. I wanted to make sure what i had asked was valid for an irreversible cycle of the surrounding

Comment: @JeffJefferson the answer is yes as Chet said but only because the system has not undergone a complete cycle